# Multi attachment email form in django

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    attach = forms.Field(widget = forms.FileInput)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

I have a form with the code as above. This form allows users to attach only a single file. If I want to allow up to 4 attachments with each mail, how do I need to modify the code?

Comment: how about a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a `FieldField` instead of `Field` for the attach field above, and just input four of them.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield